# Facebook android fragment login

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

**ERROR: CursorWrapperInner(10908): Cursor finalized without prior close()**

I've been trying to get the facebook code to work with my app. For some reason even the samples get this error? I don't know why, but here is my fragment to which I get this same error as stated above.

code:

```
package com.fragments;

public class MainDisplayFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_display_fragment, container,
                false);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this.getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Facebook login button.
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        // Set Application ID.
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends",
                "user_about_me", "user_birthday", "user_likes", "user_status"));

        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this code inside Activity? What is this for? `authButton.setFragment(this);` Have you tried shared preferences for retrieving user state? Is there any possibility `callback` returns null value for any of them?

Comment: I have had this fixed for awhile before your comment, I apologize for not posting sooner. Look below for all with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem came from moving the interaction to the activity. This way we could monitor the session states within our main activity. Unfortunately, according to the documentation it should not have been necessary but this is the fix I used for those with persisting problems.

CODE:

```
// session callback status
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    // on click listener for the login button
    public OnClickListener loginButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // call the handler
            onLoginButtonClick();

        }
    };

    // session callback
    public void onLoginButtonClick() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setCallback(callback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
        }

    }

    public void intializeSession(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // initialize the facebook session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, callback,
                        savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                        .setCallback(callback));
            }
        }

    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {

        // IF the session is opened
        if (session.isOpened()) {

            //TODO YOUR INTERACTIONS HERE WHEN OPEN

        }
        // else IF there session is closed
        else if (session.isClosed()) {

            // TODO YOUR INTERACTIONS HERE WHEN CLOSED

        }
    }
```